# Silverlight entity-bound user control design problems

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am relatively new to the Silverlight, so it tottaly possible that my question is bit confussing. Enyway, the problem is:

I need a reusable control which is used to preview and modify the data from database.
It is the Telephone edit control.

The problem is that the telephone data is stored as the entity in database ( separate table with country code, number and extension, and a set of security fields ), and I still dont see the clean way to implement it.

What have I done:

1) I have created the new user control
2) I have created the model for it to represent the data from database
3) I have declared dependency property on the silverlight control which represents the Entity object that the control is bound to
4) I have implement the dependency update callback, and this is the place where troubles have begin.

```
public partial class TelephoneControl
{

    public TelephoneModel Model
    {
        get { return (TelephoneModel)DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TelephoneProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Telephone", typeof(Telephone), typeof(TelephoneControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, TelephoneChanged));

    private static void TelephoneChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TelephoneControl) d).HandleTelephonChanged(e);
    }
    protected void HandleTelephonChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_changingContext)
        {
            _changingContext = true;

            var val = (Telephone) e.NewValue;

            if (val == null)
            {
                Model = GetNewModel();
                RaiseEntityAdded();
            }
            else
            {
                Model = GetModelByPhone(val);
            }
        }

        _changingContext = false;
    }
...........

}
```

As you can see I have not found a better place to create the model for control, rather then d.p. callback. And I have the strong filling that I did something wrong.

Comment: Custom Controls shoul be more generic, I mean they shouldn't be connected with a specific class. Use UserControl. If you attach a screenshot of the desired control, I will write a small example that explains how to use it correctly.